# Bioenergetics and equilibrium

Tags: biochemistry, bioenergetics

"The living state is a non-equilibrium steady state to be able to perform work."
I know that a "steady state" is the one in which the rate of energy gain is equal to rate of energy loss. Then how can living beings do work?  Can you simplify it?

Comment: Posting text as image isn't a best practice on SE. The same pdf should allow copying and pasting the text into your question ( [edit] ). Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Think about why body needs energy to maintain this steady state?

Comment: @Tyto alba I understand now. I have removed the image.

Comment: The clue is in the non-equilibrium part. The energy is spent to prevent collapsing to the equilibrium, that is indeed death.